# Can I draw power from one cell while charging 5 in series?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, 18650

I recently [watched this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNHDbXAmY_0) by DIY Perks and I want to build some bluetooth speakers using the electronics from a pair of Bluetooth earbuds and a class AB amp for some 10w speakers. Very similar to the video. What I want to change is the battery. He had removable 18650 cells that are charged externally. I'd like to have them internal and charged with a USB-C port.

Each speaker will be completely separate from the other (aside from a stereo Bluetooth connection).

To power each amp (one for each speaker), I'm thinking of an array of 18650 cells.
To power each earbud, I'm thinking of connecting it to ONE of the cells in the array and then connect the amp to the end terminals of the 5S array.

[This is the battery module](https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005004863183982.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm#nav-review):

[image]

So would there be issues if I connect the earbud to one of the cells and have the system charging AND have the amp connected to the end terminals of the battery?

This is what I'm thinking:

[image]

If that would be bad, then would be ok to connect to chargers in parallel from one USB-C port (perhaps with a small USB hub)? i.e. one for the 5-cell charger and one for a 1-cell charger. Both connected in parallel to one USB-C port.
So one of these:

[image]
for the earbud.

[This is the amp](https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005003071469430.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm):

[image]

Now the amp has two speaker outputs, but I'd bridge the speaker out from the earbud as the 2ch input to the amp

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an exceptionally bad idea: You charge one battery less than the others / discharge one battery more than the others, so that you would be overcharging the rest.

Don't do it.

Comment: Do you think having two battery chargers (one for the single battery and one for the 5S battery) connected to one USB port would be ok?

Comment: yeah, as long as they in combination can be configured to not draw more current than your USB bus can supply (typically, 500 mA to 1.5A); but it's also a very heavy, large, expensive solution to a simple problem: just connect your headphone amp to the 5 cells, if necessary through a switch-mode step down converter

Comment: Something like this: https://aliexpress.com/item/1005005065706512.html connected to the 5S battery to step it down to the 3.7v for the earbud. That actually makes a lot of sense and simplifies the solution!

Comment: yep, but I definitely do *not* recommend buying *any* electronics from aliexpress, you literally never know what you'll get, and the customer support always tries to blame you, unless you can prove you've been shipped a bag of dead mice instead of an electronic component, and even then they'll make you fight for it. The sellers routinely misdeclare goods to safe on import duty, which puts you in the position of tax evasion if you don't tell the import authorities and pay the difference yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all your input! Much appreciated